# Что означает стрелка вверх (^) у селектора?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть вот такой css:

```
a[href^="tel:"] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Вся запись деактивирует `cursor pointer` и вызов звонка у ссылок с `href="tel:798877665567"` Хотелось бы понять, что означает символ `^` в данной записи?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный [селектор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
[attr^=value]
```

Выбирает элементы с атрибутом `attr`, значение которого начинается с `value`.